# How to access the result returned by processor#make in after_post_process callback in Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am trying to allow uploading pdf file. When the pdf file is uploaded, a `Paperclip::Processor` will convert it into a text file in its make instance method. Then, I would like to parse the text file to populate `ActiveRecord` class. How can I access the processed file returned by the Processor in its make instance method?

The code skeleton is here:

```
module Paperclip
  class PdfToText < Processor
    ...
     def make
      dst = File.new(..)
      #do something to dst
      dst
     end
  end
end

class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :source_file, ..., :processors =>[:pdftotext]

  after_post_process :do_it

  def do_it
    # I would like to access the dst file returned in make of the processor PdfToText
  end
end
```

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
source_file.queued_for_write[:original].path
```